# How to make animation start at hovering - storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

How to make the animation start of the `TextBlock` when entering (hovering) the button

In `TextBlock`  I want that the `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent` will be in `Input2` at `MouseEnter`, How can I do that

`<EventTrigger RoutedEvent=Input2.MouseEnter` doesn't recognized

**The button:**

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Name="Input2" Click="Input_Click" MouseEnter="Input_MouseEnter" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Image Source= "C:\Users\Me\input.png"
                               Width="40" 
                               Height="40"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

**The `TextBlock`:**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="Input_Name1" Text="Input" FontSize="40" FontFamily="/10KHours;component/Font_count/#Dancing Script" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="48" Margin="65.346,33.6,-102.081,36">
                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Input_Name1" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
                                            AutoReverse="true" RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </TextBlock.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
```

Comment: What is your _specific_ problem? Have you tried anything? What didn't work? You seem to already understand how to start an animation in response to an event. Did you try that with the button? Provide a good [mcve] that shows what you did try, explain precisely what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea to change the style of the `TextBlock` is totally correct. Add a `DataTrigger` and bind it to the the `IsMouseOver` of the `Button` you are going to hover. Using the `IsMouseOver` is propaply the simplest way to get the desired information. Here is a minimal example:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Hover me"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="Input">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                    AutoReverse="true" RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Why DataTrigger? *<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">* should do the same

Comment: Yes but he needs to get the `IsMouseOver` of a different element.

Comment: Oh, now I see ;o)